# How can I unzip Office Open XML file in C# and modify its data and re-zip again?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, xlsx

From a console application written in C#, how can I :

- extract an Office Open XML file,
- Obtain the data part of it modify
- the data and re-zip it again

My motivation is to save an excel file with the formats and use it to populate cells via a console application.

Is this possible to achieve, do I need a specific library to that provides Excel files manipulation (unzipping it, modifying it etc.)

Answer (score 2):

For the zip-unzip part i think you can find easily many examples here.
To edit the excel file, I'd suggest you to have a look at Open XML SDK. With it, you can easily edit office files programmatically.
Hope it helps